# Is there a calendar for MacOS that supports a one-day view with a very narrow window?

Tags: calendar, macos

I'd grown accustomed to having having my calendar's day view as a separate, narrow window perched at the side of my screen, so I can quickly glance to see a visual representation of where my day was at and what's coming next on my agenda. It was easy with Outlook on Windows, but I'm now using a Mac and the Outlook app doesn't allow the window to be shrunken small enough to facilitate the same effect. Ideally I'm looking for something that takes up less than 15% of the width of the screen.

Outlook for Mac does offer a "task panel" sidebar that approximates what I'm looking for but there's no way to detach it from the full Outlook window:
[image: image of 400 pixel wide calendar sidebar from Outlook for Mac]

Does anyone know of an app that supports this?